# Seeking LiDAR Data for Romania?

Tags: data, lidar, romania

I need LIDAR Data for realizing a urban hydrology study in Romania.

Where can I get this data?

In particular I seek free data for Cluj-Napoca as a PhD student.

Comment: Have you tried going through your university's regular channels - surely  someone else must've needed elevation data before?

Answer (score 1):

There is some LiDAR data for Romania findable by  browsing here:

http://vterrain.org/Locations/ro/